# WSO2is SCIM query with two filters

Tags: wso2, scim2, wso2-identity-server

I understand that it is not possible to use the 'or' operator to make queries.
What alternative is there to perform a query with two filters for same attribute but diffrente query, for example:

```
scim2/Users?filter=field+sw+content-a&filter=field+sw+content-b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Git issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/5854) is still in open state. Therefore, believe this has not yet been implemented.

You can achieve your requirement using 2 SCIM calls(One for each filter). Then programatically get the `union` of the results. Same goes for `NOT` operator as well. You have to perform multiple SCIM calls and programtically obtain the end result.